# Postgresql error after installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I already have a rails project then i installed `Postgresql` and pgadmin III , I need to use posgresql in development instead of `sqlite` and production to use `heroku` , I followed the answer number two in this question [Change from SQLite to PostgreSQL in a fresh Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/how-do-you-easily-change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-rails) because i just installed `Postgresql` using synaptic center without making anything else , when i try to create a user i got an error:

```
createuser dexter
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) y
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "dexter" does not exist
```

Comment: does 'sudo -u postgres createuser' work?

Comment: but why should i create a new user without superuser role ? can you explain it for me ? because i found all answers and from searching on google doing the same step `Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n` without explanation

Comment: Hi, Mostafa, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser
```

To answer your question, from the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createuser.html):

> "If you wish to create a new superuser, you must connect as a
>   superuser, not merely with CREATEROLE privilege. Being a superuser
>   implies the ability to bypass all access permission checks within the
>   database, so superuserdom should not be granted lightly."

Given that the account you are creating is simply for granting your Rails application access, while the ability to create databases makes sense, superuser privileges is not a good idea.

Comment: I want to make my user as a blank password to use rails without out password , should i add something in sudo -u postgres createuser ?

Comment: See this question as a starting point for what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421807/set-blank-password-for-postgresql-user