# I cant login into postgres because i put an empty password

Tags: sql, postgresql, passwords

I tried once to change my postgres account password using  ALTER USER like this   `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '';` and it accept it ,

but when i tried to log in it didnt work it always geives me the error:
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

so how can i login again or change th password?

Comment: Do you have any other superusers available you can log in as?

Comment: @jjanes No I dont have other superusers I can log in, but it is ok because I didnt need to, I used the answer in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421807/set-blank-password-for-postgresql-user and it worked. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try log in without using a password as suggested in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721095/11619209), I hope it helps you

Comment: Well it didnt actually worked, but thanks.